# Node.js connecting through ssh

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh

I have a node.js server that works but needs to be set up for ssh connections:

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
var db = mysql.createConnection({

    host: 'hostname',
    user: 'username',
    password: '12345',
    database: '12345',
    port: 3306,
    socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
})

db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err)
})
```

I'm aware that there are ssh npm libraries for this purpose, however the options available (ssh2, node-sshclient, etc) appear to deal with pretty intricate features that may overcomplicate things. I'm looking for the simplest way to connect to my mysql db through ssh. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to connect to database via ssh?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are running a linux/unix system do the following:

Connect to your mysql server via `ssh` and proxy the mysql port (default is 3306) via this ssh tunnel.

This works as follows:

**1** Type in `screen` (to start a screen session which is permanent even if the shell gets closed).

**2** Type into screen shell:

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 your_servers_domain_or_ip -lyour_login_name
```

**3** Enter your ssh password / or use a PKI auth to avoid manual steps

**4** Done... now it’s possible to connect MySQL like you would do when it’s installed on the same machine as your application.

Connect to MySQL from node.js like below:

```
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1', // Important to connect to localhost after connecting via ssh in screen
    user: 'username',
    password: '12345',
    database: '12345',
    port: 3306
});
```

Comment: I'm using a mac terminal, I typed 'screen', entered in the information you provided with my domain and password,and succesfully connected into my server via ssh. However, when I run my server.js node file the problem still persists. I'm receiving:                                             { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }                                                            Is there a step here that I missed? I'm able to query successfully with this code on servers that don't require ssh.

Comment: After you connected via ssh you need to connect your node.ja app to localhost. Because with that ssh command in screen you make port 3306 from mysql server available on your local machine

Comment: @Bernhard what for windows? I am using putty to connect to my server and have a node.js app locally that I would like to connect to the database using ssh.

Comment: @aidonsnous If you're using https://www.cygwin.com/ i guess it will work. But then maybe try to run your node app via cygwin too. Many of my colleagues use this on windows to have a linux like environment. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the info , but when i type the command in the terminal , of course after changing ip and user , i log in my vps , and it's working but when i type exit the connection are terminated . so how to keep connection running without loging into my vps

Comment: @The4thpyramid If you're using `sceen` command beforehand the session persists even when you close the terminal. Alternatively when you're target server supports PKI authentication you could setup connection on system start see e.g. here https://askubuntu.com/questions/884138/ssh-connection-to-a-machine-on-boot

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's preferrable to instantiate the SSH tunnel connection dynamically (in code) rather than separately using OS libraries. For example, it makes it easier to automatically close the connection, share the environment with other developers, or conditionally use an SSH tunnel depending on the environment.

With packages such as [tunnel-ssh](https://github.com/agebrock/tunnel-ssh), this is easy. Building on the example provided, the connection code would look like:

```js
import { createSSHTunnel } from "./sshTunnel";

const { srcAddr, srcPort } = await createSSHTunnel();

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: srcAddr,
    port: srcPort,
    user: 'username',
    password: '12345',
    database: '12345'  
});
```

With all logic cleanly abstracted away in the `sshTunnel` module, that could look like:

```js
// sshTunnel.js

import { createTunnel } from "tunnel-ssh";

export async function createSSHTunnel(srcAddr = "127.0.0.1", srcPort = 12345) {
  const tunnelOptions = {
    autoClose: true,
  };
  const serverOptions = {
    port: srcPort,
  };
  const sshOptions = {
    host: process.env.SSH_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.SSH_PORT),
    username: process.env.SSH_TUNNEL_USER,
    password: process.env.SSH_TUNNEL_PASSWORD,
  };
  const forwardOptions = {
    srcAddr: srcAddr,
    srcPort: srcPort,
    dstAddr: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dstPort: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  };
  try {
    await createTunnel(
      tunnelOptions,
      serverOptions,
      sshOptions,
      forwardOptions
    );
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
      // Assume port is uniquely used by SSH tunnel, so existing connection can be reused
      console.log(`Returning existing SSH tunnel on ${srcAddr}:${srcPort}.`);
      return { srcAddr, srcPort };
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  console.log(`SSH tunnel successfully created on ${srcAddr}:${srcPort}.`);
  return { srcAddr, srcPort };
}
```

Remarks:

- The SSH tunnel arbitrarily uses local port 12345
- The environment variables involved are:

  - `DB_HOST`: the database hostname
  - `DB_PORT`: the database port, 3306 in the original MySQL example, 5432 for Postgres etc.
  - `SSH_HOST`: the hostname of the machine serving the SSH tunnel
  - `SSH_PORT`: the port of the machine serving the SSH tunnel
  - `SSH_TUNNEL_USER`: the username for the SSH tunnel
  - `SSH_TUNNEL_PASSWORD`: the password for the SSH tunnel

Comment: finally! worked beautifully thank you!!