# How to use Node.js to make a SSH tunneling connection to a MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, mongoose, ssh-tunnel

My credentials work perfectly with Robomongo but I can't make the connection with node.js
I have tried to make the connection using ssh2 and tunnel-ssh npm module and failed both times.
-The mongo connection does not require a password
-The ssh connection is made with a pem key

This is the code I've used with ssh2 module, I can establish the tunneling correctly but the mongo connection fails

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    //mongo connection
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/');
        var db = mongoose.connection;
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.once('open', function() {
            console.log("database connection established");
            var users = db.collection('user');
            var getallUsers = function (date, callback){
                users.find({}).toArray(function(err,data){
                    callback(data);
                })
            };
            getallUsers(null, function (data){
                console.log('data :'+  data);
            });
        });
    //end of mongo connection
}).connect({
    host: '**.**.**.**.**',
    port: 22,
    username: 'ec2-user',
    privateKey: key
});
```

And the code the tunnel-ssh

```
var config = {
    dstPort: 27000,
    user: 'ec2-user',
    host: '**.**.**.**.**',
    privateKey: key
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }
    console.log('database connection initalizing');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/');

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {

        console.log("database connection established");

        var users = db.collection('user');
        var getallUsers = function (date, callback){
            users.find({}).toArray(function(err,data){
                callback(data);
            })
        };
        getallUsers(null, function (data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
});
```

I'm not sure whether to use the regular MongoDB connection string after establishing the tunnel or referring to the database as localhost such as
mongodb://localhost:portnumber.
or
mongodb://databasepath.subpath.mongodbdns.com:27000

Localhost gives me a permission denied error, the latter gives me a timeout

Comment: Generic options on how to build an SSH tunnel for a Node.js application (which of course works for MongoDB as well) are discussed as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687932/node-js-connecting-through-ssh/75547238)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mscdex mentioned ssh2 isn't a good module to use to make an ssh tunnel connection to a database. tunnel-ssh is more appropriate.

Here are the configuration options I've used :

dstPort: remote database connection port

localPort: same as dstPort, It'll be the port you'll use for your local machine

username: SSH username,

host: SSH address

dstHost: database connection url (...mongodbns.com) ,

privateKey: SSH key

Then once your tunnel is connected connect via mongoose to your localhost such as mondodb://localhost:27000 (use the localport you defined in localPort)

```
var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/');
    //...rest of mongoose connection
}
```

Comment: I am getting this>>
**Error: All configured authentication methods failed**
note:i am using **require('mongodb').MongoClient ,require('tunnel-ssh'),var config = {
    username: 'root',
    Password: 'xxxxxx',
    host: "x.x.11.130",
    dstHost: "x.x.11.130",
    port: 22,
    dstHost:url,
    dstPort: 10945,
    localPort: 10945
};**

Comment: FYI, tunnel-ssh internally use ssh2 to establish the tunnel

Comment: @user3382714 does dstHost look something like "mongodb+src//user:pass@mongohostname" ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `mongoose` does not support passing in a stream to use as the underlying connection, you will have to listen on a local port (e.g. 27000) and forward incoming connections to that port over the ssh connection.

Fortunately there exists third party modules that build on `ssh2` that provide this kind of functionality for you, such as [`tunnel-ssh`](https://github.com/Finanzchef24-GmbH/tunnel-ssh). Try using one of those.

Comment: thanks for the response I've spent a good amount of time on tunnel-ssh as well, I couldn't get it to connect, my code for tunnel-ssh is above.

Comment: did you try `username` instead of `user` in your config object?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with official mongodb client for node

```js
const sshTunnelConfig = {
  agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
  username: 'ec2-user',
  privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('./path-to-ec2-key.pem'),
  host: '3.98.174.12', //IP adress of VPS which is the SSH server
  port: 22,
  dstHost: 'docdb-cluster-vmabwxueb51y.eu-central-1.docdb.amazonaws.com',
  dstPort: 27017,
  localHost: '127.0.0.1',
  localPort: 27018 //or anything else unused you want
};


const connectionProperties = {
  sslValidate: true,
  ssl: true,
  sslCA: [fs.readFileSync('rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem')],
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  authMechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
  auth: {
    user: 'docdbuser',
    password: '<PASSWORD>'
  },
  tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: true,
  tlsAllowInvalidCertificates: true,
};

tunnel(sshTunnelConfig, async (error, server) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('SSH connection error: ', error);
  }
  
   const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   const client = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27018/', propertiesConnection,
    function(err, client) {
      if(err)
        throw err;

      //Specify the database to be used
      db = client.db('database-name');

      //Specify the collection to be used
      col = db.collection('collection-name');

      //Insert a single document
      col.insertOne({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'}, function(err, result){
        //Find the document that was previously written
        col.findOne({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'}, function(err, result){
          //Print the result to the screen
          console.log(result);

          //Close the connection
          client.close()
        });
      });
    });
  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that codes but are you sure that block is working well? Im trying to do same thing. Ssh connection is ok, but after that, i cant connect mongo client. I tried with your sample codes and same again.

Comment: propertiesConnection vs. connectionProperties doesn't make sense....has this been tested?

Comment: The `sshTunnelConfig` object's properties seem to match the interface of [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh). The following q/a should be more useful in getting this to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903566/node-js-ssh-tunneling-to-mongodb-using-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Because all the answers above didn't work for me for some reason, I am posting the code that worked for me. I'm tunneling from my Nodejs webserver to an PostgreSQL Database on an online ubuntu vm:

```
const SSH2Promise = require('ssh2-promise');
const {Client } = require('pg');

let config = {
    host:process.env.SSH_HOST, //your machine IP-address like [193.xxx.xx.xxx]
    port:process.env.SSH_PORT, //port you ssh to, probably 22
    username: process.env.SSH_USERNAME, //username of your machine
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../" + process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)) //your ssh private key to log in
};

function getDBConfig(port) {

    return new Client({
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        port: port,
    });
}

async function makeDb(port) {
    let dbClient = getDBConfig(port);
    await dbClient.connect();
    return {
        async query(sql) {
            return (await dbClient.query(sql)).rows;
        }
    };
}

const sshConn = new SSH2Promise(config);
let con;
(async function(){
    await sshConn.connect();
    console.log("Connection established");
    let tunnel = await sshConn.addTunnel({remoteAddr: process.env.REMOTE_HOST, remotePort: process.env.REMOTE_PORT});
//Remote host: just use 127.0.0.1
//Remote port: port where your db is connected to ex: 5432
    con = await makeDb(tunnel.localPort);
})();

//use connection like this:
await con.query("SELECT ... sql statement here);
```

Comment: getting con as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Connect to a private Amazon RDS instance from local node js application
This will allow you to securely connect to the RDS instance from your local machine.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUuRQ-oorMQLahG6egHb4-bg/how-can-i-connect-to-a-private-amazon-rds-instance-from-local-node-js-application-which-was-earlier-using-non-ssh-sequelize-connection