# Node.js SSH Tunneling to MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, mongoose

I have two Mongo DBs. One for my dev environment, one for production as seen here from my Robomongo setup:

[image: Two Mongo DBs]

The production db is SSH tunneled to my Digital Ocean virtual server as seen here (specifics have been changed obviously). This setup works fine when connecting to/from my production website:

[image: SSH Tunnel Settings]

I am now working on a different/related project and need to connect my ***local*** machine to my ***production*** DB, so I assumed I'd need to use something like [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh) to get it done. I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514734/2690558) as an example, but I'm either getting `Error: (SSH) Channel open failure: open failed` OR it's connecting to my Dev db (when I use 27017 as my dstHost/dstPort/localPort). I must be thinking about this wrong or I'm being dumb with my configuration. I am admittedly a total Mongo/Mongoose novice, so both are equally possible. Any advice?

```
var fs = require("fs");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');

//===== db connection =====

var config = {
    username:'my.username',
    host:'my.ip.address',
    agent : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa'),
    port:22,
    dstHost:'mongodb://localhost:27000/mydbname',
    dstPort:27000,
    localHost:'127.0.0.1',
    password:'mypassword',
    localPort: 27000
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/mydbname');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        // we're connected!
        console.log("DB connection successful");
        // console.log(server);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! very useful! The only thing that I had to change is, in my case, the config must have "passphrase" instead of "password".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dstHost` needs to be a hostname/IP, not a MongoDB connection string. In this particular case, you can actually omit `dstHost`, `localHost`, and `localPort` in this particular case because they already default to the values you're providing.

Comment: Well, progress at least. Commenting out those three, now I get `Error: (SSH) Channel open failure: Connection refused`. Mean anything to you? Off I go to the Google machine...

Comment: You're not using the same port as you show in your screenshot. So try changing it accordingly to match that instead. You'll also need to change the port in your connection string as well.

Comment: That's the ticket. Painfully obvious and fixed in 5 seconds after reading your comment this morning. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 24):

The final working config for future reference. Thanks to mscdex -- I simply needed to provide the *correct* dstPort and include it in my Mongo URI string (the 27017). So simple.

```
var config = {
    username:'myusername',
    host:'my.ip.address',
    agent : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa'),
    port:22,
    dstPort:27017,
    password:'mypassword'
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydbname');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        // we're connected!
        console.log("DB connection successful");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your solution it is pretty much helpful but i had to add passphrase to make it work. Thank you very much :)

Comment: what is agent please?

Answer (score 9):

Or if you don't want to change your code, provided that you have your ssh public key on the tunnel server, you can create a tunnel via ssh on the terminal:

```
ssh -fNL <local_port>:<mongodb_server_hostname_or_ip>:<mongodb_server_port> <tunnel_server_user>@<tunnel_server_hostname_or_ip>
```

Example with made-up IPs connecting to a fake AWS EC2 AMI Linux

```
ssh -fNL 27000:101.202.10.20:27000 ec2-user@33.44.55.66
```

Now this `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/mydbname');` works like a charm. ;)

Comment: Best answer IMO !

Comment: May I ask you how to connect through ssh tunnel with the user name password of MongoDB? @Titou

Comment: @HaiAlison You do not use mongoDB username/pwd to connect through ssh. You pass the username/pwd as parameters of the mongodb connexion query through an established tunnel.

Comment: thank you @Titou, I've been fixing my problem with config mongo.conf file added IP address server to bindIp, and it worked.

Comment: I am trying this solution with mongo atlas srv string but it is showing srv string do not need port and if I am trying it without srv it is showing no address associated with hostname, can you help please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434045/connecting-to-mongo-srv-string-using-mongoose-nestjs-with-ssh-tunneling

Comment: @RaghuChahar, I saw you already fix your issue. Interesting tool; thanks for sharing.