# how to connect another machine mongodb database inside local network ?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I follow this mongoose document [enter link description here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/waterDB');
```

Using This, I can connect local machine `waterDB`mongoDB DataBase

My Personal Machine Local IP : `192.168.1.5`

My Server Machine Local IP : `192.168.1.100`

Both machine have `waterDB` DataBase . There is no username and password for both DB

I wanted to connect Server Machine `waterDB` Inside My Personal Machine.

According To This : `mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');`

I try : `mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.1.100:27017/waterDB');`

But,

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [192.168.1.100:27017] on first connect
at null.<anonymous> (/home/water/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at emit (events.js:169:7)
..........
```

Any solution for err ?

Thank (@_@)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It might be a problem with your MongoDB instance listening on localhost only.
You can change the [bind address](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) in MongoDB's configuration file. The config file may be located in `/etc/mongodb.conf` or `/etc/mongod.conf`. There are also 2 config file formats:

Old format (still supported):

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

YAML (version 2.6+):

```
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

After changing the config file you have to restart the MongoDB server.

Comment: Why `0.0.0.0` though? What does it mean in this case? EDIT: Found the answer to my question: "To bind to all IPv4 addresses, enter 0.0.0.0." from the `bind address` link.

Answer (score 3):

Try without the Port no.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.1.100/waterDB');
```

this should work for you.

But make sure both are connected on the same network, if you are connected on other network than your server is, then it wont work

Comment: Are you sure mongodb is running on the server machine?

Comment: In both machine. running mongodb. I check both individual.  I need to know. how to connect mongodb database but it has another machine and both machine have same network. hope any doc ....

Answer (score 2):

For me (using windows and mongo version 6, and remotely connecting from Mac), after changing config file to

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: "*" # OR 0.0.0.0
```

Then starting server with: mongod, it was still binding to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). I had to start the server with: mongod --bind_ip_all

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use SSH tunnel in this case. Refer to the following link which shows how you can create SSH tunnel.
[Node.js SSH Tunneling to MongoDB using Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903566/node-js-ssh-tunneling-to-mongodb-using-mongoose)