# How to connect with mongoDB via SSH

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh

```
const config = {
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  host: "0.0.0.0",
  port: 22,
  dstPort: 27017,
};

tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
  }
  console.log("SSH ok");
  mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/megaparking?retryWrites=true&w=majority'"
  );
  console.log("Connect ok");
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "DB connection error:"));
  db.once("open", function () {
    console.log("DB connection successful");

    
  });
});
```

I want to connect with MongoDB installed on server, but I have the issue:

```
127.0.0.1:27017 is already in use cause
```

I was opening sever locally and I want connected with MongoDB on dedicated server, which has also 127.0.0.1 host and port 27017. What I should do with that code? Or maybe I should create a MongoDB connection string by this data?

The issue:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1503:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 27017
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: are you trying to connect to MongoDB on another server? in that case can you use the Fully Qualified domain name of the MongoDB server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js SSH Tunneling to MongoDB using Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903566/node-js-ssh-tunneling-to-mongodb-using-mongoose)

Comment: i am trying to connect with mongodb installed on the server from hosting